# NAS does not mount during boot

Tags: mount, fstab, nas

I would like to mount a NAS automatically during start up, and have inserted the following line in /etc/fstab:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=xxxxxx,password=xxxxxx //nas8d5ec9.local/public/ /mnt/qnap_backup
```

The script does not mount the NAS. 
However, when I just cut and paste the mount code into a terminal it works as intended.

What do I need to add and/or change?

Comment: `/etc/fstab` is **not** a script - it's a configuration file with a very specific format

Answer (score 1):

The format for mounting cifs shares via /etc/fstab is:

```
//servername/sharename  /media/windowsshare  cifs  username=msusername,password=mspassword,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0
```

There is a article about mounting cifs in linux on wiki.ubuntu.com: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Comment: Thanks! I have added `//nas8d5ec9.local/public/ /mnt/qnap_backup cifs guest,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0` to the fstab file. Then,  `sudo mount -av` gives `mount error(13): Permission denied`.

Comment: Maybe `sec=ntlmv2` will help ?

Comment: No, that didn't work. Same message.

Comment: Have you tried with `username=` and `password=` parameters, as you used in your manual mount. Maybe `guest` doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. No success.